# have populated radio buttons, want to use submit button to print the value out

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to grab the values from the radio buttons? say it gets populated in the radio button and the options are Abuelos, Boogie Burger, Pad Thai, Coalition Pizza, Wild Eggs. Is there a way I can pull those values out and have it print out after hitting a submit button?

I also don't want the value to be redirected to another page. I just want it to print out below the submit button. I also don't want the user to be able to select a value after they hit the submit button

I am trying to make a voting poll where options are taken from multiple arrays and then someone can pick a value from the radio button and hit a submit button with their option printed out. That way the user can tell what they voted for.

part of the HTML code:

```
    <form action="" id="food-form"></form>
```

Javascript code:

```
var mexicanFood = ["Caliente Mexican", "Abuelos", "Luciana's"],
    asianFood = ["Omoni Korean", "Super Bowl Pho", "Sichuan Chinese", "Tian Fu Asian Bistro"],
    americanFood = ["Boogie Burger", "City Barbeque", "The North End BBQ", "Wolfies Grill", "Bubs", "Fire on the Monon"];
    pizza = ["Coalition Pizza", "Mackenzie River Pizza, Grill & Pub", "Bazbeaux Pizza", "Mellow Mushroom"]
    thaiFood = ["Pad Thai", "Jasmine Thai", "Thai Orchid"]
    notCategory = ["Jamaican Reggae Grill", "Mudbugs", "Yats", "Kolache Factory", ]
    breakfast = ["Wild Eggs", "Egg and I", "Another Broken Egg Cafe", "Cafe Patachou"]

function createRandomArray(arraySize) {
    var allFoods = mexicanFood.concat(asianFood).concat(americanFood).concat(pizza).concat(thaiFood).concat(notCategory).concat(breakfast),
        randomFoods = [];

    if (arraySize <= allFoods.length) {
        randomFoods = [
            mexicanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(mexicanFood)],
            asianFood[getRandomArrayIndex(asianFood)],
            americanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(americanFood)],
            pizza[getRandomArrayIndex(pizza)],
            thaiFood[getRandomArrayIndex(thaiFood)],
            notCategory[getRandomArrayIndex(notCategory)],
            breakfast[getRandomArrayIndex(breakfast)]
        ]; // at least one from each

        // remove the ones that were initially added from each
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[0]), 1);
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[1]), 1);
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[2]), 1);

        for (var i = 0; i < arraySize - 3; i++) {
            var randomIndex = getRandomArrayIndex(allFoods);

            randomFoods.push(allFoods[randomIndex]);
            allFoods.splice(randomIndex, 1);
        }

        return randomFoods;
    }

    return allFoods; // requesting more items of food than the amount available, so just add them all
}

function getRandomArrayIndex(array) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

var randomFoods = createRandomArray(5);

for (var i = 0; i < randomFoods.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('food-form').innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="food" value="' + randomFoods[i] + '"> ' + randomFoods[i] + '<br>';
}
```

Comment: when you submit the form using GET method, a query parameter `food=xxxxx` will be appended to your request url. Just read that and show it back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector('input[name=food]:checked').value` to get the selected value.

```js
var mexicanFood = ["Caliente Mexican", "Abuelos", "Luciana's"],
  asianFood = ["Omoni Korean", "Super Bowl Pho", "Sichuan Chinese", "Tian Fu Asian Bistro"],
  americanFood = ["Boogie Burger", "City Barbeque", "The North End BBQ", "Wolfies Grill", "Bubs", "Fire on the Monon"];
pizza = ["Coalition Pizza", "Mackenzie River Pizza, Grill & Pub", "Bazbeaux Pizza", "Mellow Mushroom"]
thaiFood = ["Pad Thai", "Jasmine Thai", "Thai Orchid"]
notCategory = ["Jamaican Reggae Grill", "Mudbugs", "Yats", "Kolache Factory", ]
breakfast = ["Wild Eggs", "Egg and I", "Another Broken Egg Cafe", "Cafe Patachou"]

function createRandomArray(arraySize) {
  var allFoods = mexicanFood.concat(asianFood).concat(americanFood).concat(pizza).concat(thaiFood).concat(notCategory).concat(breakfast),
    randomFoods = [];

  if (arraySize <= allFoods.length) {
    randomFoods = [
      mexicanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(mexicanFood)],
      asianFood[getRandomArrayIndex(asianFood)],
      americanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(americanFood)],
      pizza[getRandomArrayIndex(pizza)],
      thaiFood[getRandomArrayIndex(thaiFood)],
      notCategory[getRandomArrayIndex(notCategory)],
      breakfast[getRandomArrayIndex(breakfast)]
    ]; // at least one from each

    // remove the ones that were initially added from each
    allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[0]), 1);
    allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[1]), 1);
    allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[2]), 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < arraySize - 3; i++) {
      var randomIndex = getRandomArrayIndex(allFoods);
      randomFoods.push(allFoods[randomIndex]);
      allFoods.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    }

    return randomFoods;
  }

  return allFoods; // requesting more items of food than the amount available, so just add them all
}

function getRandomArrayIndex(array) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

var randomFoods = createRandomArray(5);

for (var i = 0; i < randomFoods.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('food-form').innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="food" value="' + randomFoods[i] + '"> ' + randomFoods[i] + '<br>';
}

function print() {
  var t = document.querySelector('input[name=food]:checked');

  if (t == null)
    console.log('No value selected');
  else
    console.log(t.value);
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="food-form">
</form>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="print()">
```